# remove from , and transfer to next cell in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

remove from , and transfer to next cell in pandas
for eg,

| city | country |
| --- | --- |
| Toronto,Canada | N/A |

output:

| city | country |
| --- | --- |
| Toronto,Canada | Canada |

Answer (score 1):

If need replace missing value in `country` column by last value after split `city` by `,` use:

```
df['country'] = df['country'].fillna(df['city'].str.split(',').str[-1])
```

Or if need assign all column in `country` column:

```
df['country'] = df['city'].str.split(',').str[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a word regex `\w+` anchored to the end of the string (`$`) to get the last word:

```
# replacing all values
df['country'] = df['city'].str.extract('(\w+)$', expand=False)

# only updating NaNs
df.loc[df['country'].isna(), 'country'] = df['city'].str.extract('(\w+)$', expand=False)
```

output:

```
             city country
0  Toronto,Canada  Canada
```

Alternatively, you can use the `([^,]+)$` regex that is more permissive (any terminal character except `,`)